# Number of subsets of size 3 that are divisible by a given small prime

Tags: arrays, subset-sum

My problem is to find the number of subsets of size 3 of a given array of size 'N' whose sum is divisible by a given small prime number 'P' and the constraints are like:

1. N<=500
2. P<50
3. all integer values are <1000

   I couldn't find any way and wanted to solve the given problem with optimal time and space complexity?.

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please add any current attempts?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I haven't got any good idea to solve it. That's why I asked it here

Comment: this isnt a do it for you site, you have to attempt it yourself and come here only if you have issues

Answer (score -1):

Hmm... here's an idea: to find if the sum is divisable by P, you don't really care about the integers themselves - only their reminder when divided by P. So you can replace all integers with their reminders. Then count them. You don't care about their order anywyay - just how many there are of each. Next, for any P, you can enumerate all posible combinations of 3 reminders and see which yield 0, P or 2P when summed. For all those combinations, see in how many ways you can get them by looking at the counts.